# Prove $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac {1} {n\ln(n)\sqrt{\ln^3{n}}}$ is divergent.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Evaluate if the following series is convergent or divergent: $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac {1} {n\ln(n)\sqrt{\ln^3{n}}}$.

After checking the solution I found out the series was divergent. I tried to use the comparison test or Weierstrass's test to evaluate the series. I started by using the inequality $\ln(n)\leqslant n$ in the following way:

$\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac {1} {n\ln(n)\sqrt{\ln^3{n}}}>\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac {1} {n^2+\sqrt{n^3}}>\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac {1} {n^2+{n^3}}$.
Since $\frac {1} {x^2+{x^3}}$ is monotone decreasing I computed: $\int_\limits{1}^{\infty}\frac {1} {x^2+{x^3}}=\int_\limits{1}^{\infty}-\frac {1} {x}+\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{x^2}=1-\ln(2)$, so the series $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac {1} {n^2+{n^3}}$ converges. I tried to find a series in between that would diverge but I have not come to an idea of what the numerator should be.

**Question:**

How can I prove the series $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac {1} {n\ln(n)\sqrt{\ln^3{n}}}$ to be divergent?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it converges, by direct application of the integral test.

Comment: Note: I assumed that $\ln^3(x)$ meant $\left(\ln(x) \right)^3$. Perhaps you meant something else?  In any case, you should edit to clarify.

Comment: @lulu This exercise comes from a book. I have noticed the author to write ($\ln\ln(x)$) when he wants the composition, so I assume here that the author is referring to $\ln^3(x)=(\ln(x))^3$ as you stated. I am little bit confused regarding  the solution once it states that the series converge.

Comment: Well, the posted solutions seem comprehensive.  If you understand it to mean the cube you get a convergent series, if you understand it to mean composition you get a divergent series.

Comment: If $\ln^3 x$ means $\ln(\ln(\ln x)$  then the series is divergent.

Comment: @PedroGomes, as in an earlier question, you have your sum-comparing inequalities pointing in the **wrong** direction. When *denominators* get big, their *fractions* get small.

Comment: @BarryCipra             As I knew the series diverged due to the fact I checked the solution I tried to find a smaller sum that would diverge.

Comment: @BarryCipra I found out what you mean. Please check the update!

Comment: @PedroGomes, that's good.  The next step is to understand that, when you're trying to show that something diverges (to infinity), it doesn't help to show it's bigger than something that turns out to converge; you want to show it's bigger than something that you already know diverges. In this case, that's not so easy. Incidentally, some authors will write $f(f(x))$ for the first iteration but $f^n(x)$ or $f^{(n)}(x)$ for higher iterations, such as $f^3(x)=f(f(f(x)))$. That's probably what $\ln^3x$ here means.

Comment: On further reflection, there's a snag with the interpretation of $\ln^3n$ as $\ln\ln\ln n$:  It's not defined for $n=2$, and it's negative for $3\le n\le15$.  But this could be an oversight on the part of the author, who was otherwise careful not to start the sum at $n=1$. If I were the OP, I'd take another careful look at the book and then ask an instructor about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For series $\dfrac 1{n^\alpha\ln(n)^\beta}$ the easiest test is the [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test).

In this case for $\alpha=1$ and $\beta=\frac 52>1$ it should converge.

Unless your $\ln^3 n$ meant $\ln(\ln(\ln(n)))$ in which case you would have $\dfrac 1{n^\alpha\ln(n)^\beta\ln(\ln(\ln(n)))^\gamma}$ with $\alpha=\beta=1$ and $\gamma=\frac 12<1$ so it is divergent.

Answer (score 5):

It is well-known a *Bertrand's series*:
$$\sum_{n\ge 2}\frac 1{n^\alpha\log^\beta\! n}$$
converges if and only if

- $\alpha>1$ (by comparison with the Riemann series $\;\sum_{n}\frac 1{n^\alpha}$);
- or $\alpha=1$ and $\beta>1$ (by the integral test).

Answer (score 3):

Use Cauchy's condensation test.

$$\frac {2^n} {2^n\ln(2^n)\sqrt{\ln^3{2^n}}} = \frac{1}{n\ln2 \cdot (n \ln2)^{3/2}} = \frac{1}{(\ln2)^{5/2} \, n^{5/2}}$$

So it's convergent.

Answer (score 2):

Does $ln^3(x)$ mean iterated 3 times or cubed? If cubed I think is false, if iterated 3 times true.

Hint: (Cauchy condensation test.) For a non-negative, decreasing sequence of reals $f(n)$:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(n) \hbox{    converges iff } \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^n f(2^n) \hbox{     converges }$$